# SSLContext.getInstance(String): Is there a way to always get the latest TLS?

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.3

Today, I write: `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3")`, but I would prefer something like: `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSvLatest")`.

I cannot find a direct way using the existing API/ctor.  Is this possible to simulate?

One hacky idea:

```
private static SSLContext
_getSSLContextTLSLatest()
throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    for (int i = 9; i >= 3; --i)
    {
        final String protocol = "TLSv1." + i;
        try {
            final SSLContext x = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol);
            return x;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("SSLContext: Failed to final TLS latest");
}
```

Note: Please re-tag this question if better tags can be used.

Comment: based on this specification: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#sslcontext-algorithms there is no string for latest version

Comment: @SquidXTV Yes, this I why I wrote *simulate*.

Comment: And what if next version, if that happens, is TLS2? Or TLS42? Or TLS 1.11? Your code will seem to work but won't really use the "latest" or best version. Today, there is really no reason to use anything else than 1.3, and I believe it is best to just hardcode that (if you can be 100% sure to connect only to hosts not requiring anything else). Separate: there is no introspection possible in that library to just know what is defined?